# Request rows with amount IS NULL (IS NOT NULL) cells in Sqlite3 (SELECT command)

Tags: sqlite, select, null, row, cell

Is it possible to create a request in Sqlite3 of the SELECT type, which will contain the condition "select a row where amount NULL (or IS NOT NULL) cells will be more (less) a certain number"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE (col1 IS NULL) + (col2 IS NULL) + (col3 IS NULL) + .... > ?
```

Each of the expressions `(colX IS NULL)` or `(colX IS NOT NULL)` evaluates to `1` for `true` or `0` for `false`, so you can compare their sum to the number `?` that you want.